# Бинарный поиск. Индексно-последовательный поиск. Нахождение диапазона, а не конкретного числа

Tags: c++, алгоритм, поиск

Вот мои два поиска. Бинарный и Индексно-последовательный. Не могу разобраться, как можно ими пользоваться, если, допустим, нужно найти какой-то диапазон, а не конкретное число, гуглил, ничего дельного не нашел, помогите. Например, каких чисел больше относительно 50(т.е. левая часть массива больше или правая) или вообще любой пример с диапазоном, а не конкретным ключом? Каким должно быть условие или вообще хоть что-нибудь:)

```
//БИНАРНЫЙ ПОИСК
void binary_search(Table *table) {
        int left = 0, right = SIZE - 1;
        int mid, search = -1;

        cout << "\n\n\t\t\t\tБИНАРНЫЙ ПОИСК";

        while (left < right) {
            mid = (left + right) / 2;

            if (table[mid].key == key) {
                search = mid;
                break;
            }

            if (key < table[mid].key)
                right = mid - 1;
            else
                left = mid + 1;
        }
        if (search == -1)
            cout << "\nИскомого ключа не существует в таблице!";
        else
            cout << "\n" << "Двоичный поиск по ключу: " << table[search].key;
    }
//ИНДЕКСНО_ПОСЛЕДОВАТЕЛЬНЫЙ
void index_sequence_search(Table *table) {
        int k[3], index[4];
        int i = 0, j = 0;

        for (; i < SIZE; i += 4, ++j) {
            k[j] = table[i].key;
            index[j] = i;
        }

        int indsize = j;
        index[j] = SIZE - 1;

        cout << "\n\n\t\t\tИНДЕКСНО-ПОСЛЕДОВАТЕЛЬНЫЙ ПОИСК";

        for (j = 0; j < indsize; ++j) {
            if (key < k[j])
                break;
        }
        if (j == 0)
            i = 0;
        else i = index[j - 1];
        int rez = -1;
        for (; i < index[j]; ++i)
            if (key == table[i].key) {
                rez = i;
                cout << "\n" << "Индексно-последовательный поиск по ключу: " << table[rez].key;
            }
        if (rez == -1) {
            cout << "\nИскомого ключа не существует в таблице!";
            return;
        }
```

Comment: В обоих случаях у вас есть таблица с отсортированными значениями. Когда надо искать интервал находите сначала меньший элемент, если его нет, берете первый, который больше него (любой из алгоритмов выведет вас в таблице к этому месту). После этого точно так же ищите вторую границу диапазона, но берете предыдущий элемент, перед тем, который больше ключа. (для ускорения работы можно искать не с начала, а только в правой части таблицы, относительно первого ключа).

Comment: ну с индексно-последовательным у меня получилось(ниже скину), а с бинарным не получается, напридумал  уже кучу способов ни один не подошел.

Answer (score 1):

Обычно подразумевается, что результатом поиска является индекс в массиве, то есть функция которая реализует алгоритм поиска возвращает индекс найденного элемента. К слову, в ваших реализациях это слабо выражено. Чтобы узнать каких элементов больше, слева или справа, нужно просто проверить найденный индекс, общее количество ведь известно заранее.

Как искать дипазоны. Если диапазон задан двумя ключами, то есть начальным и конечным ключом искомого диапазона. То просто ищите индекс начального ключа, затем конечного, в результате у вас должны появиться два индекса, которые и образуют искомый диапазон.

Если диапазон задан ключом и количеством элементов слева (обычно). То еще проще, ищите иднекс указанного ключа, затем к найденному индексу прибавляете количество элементов слева и получаете конечный индекс диапазона.

Answer (score 0):

Вот, индексно-последовательный получился, не знаю, возможно, я наворотил и можно намного проще сделать, но работает исправно. С бинарным поиском все плохо, он работает, только если я ввожу в последовательность 50, но если 50-ти нет, то он некорректно работает.

```
//индексно-последовательный поиск
void index_sequence_search(Table *table) {
    int k[3], index[4];
    int i = 0, j = 0;

    for (; i < SIZE; i += 4, ++j) {
        k[j] = table[i].key;
        index[j] = i;
    }

    int indsize = j;
    index[j] = SIZE - 1;

    cout << "\n\n\t\t\tИНДЕКСНО-ПОСЛЕДОВАТЕЛЬНЫЙ ПОИСК";

    for (j = 0; j < indsize; ++j) {
        if (key < k[j])
            break;
    }
    if (j == 0)
        i = 0;
    else i = index[j - 1];
    int rez = -1;                  //Для индекса, чтобы в дальнейшем определить в какой части чисел больше
    for (; i < index[j]; ++i) {
        if (key > table[i].key) {
            if (int k = i + 1 == index[j]) //Если к последней итерации ключ не найден и следующий элемент последний, 
                rez = index[j];            //rez принимает индекс последнего элемента
            continue;
        }
        if (key <= table[i].key) {
            rez = i;
            break;
        }
    }
    if (rez != -1) {
        if (rez == SIZE / 2) {
            cout << "\nРавны стороны!";
            return;
        }
        if (rez > SIZE / 2)
            cout << "\nВ левой части относительно 50 чисел больше, чем в правой части!";
        else
            cout << "\nВ правой части относительно 50 чисел больше, чем в левой части!";
    }
}


//бинарный поиск
void binary_search(Table *table) {
    int left = 0, right = SIZE - 1;
    int mid, search = -1;

    cout << "\n\n\t\t\t\tБИНАРНЫЙ ПОИСК";

    while (left <= right) {
        mid = (left + right) / 2;
        if (table[mid].key == key) {
            search = mid;
            break;
        }
        if (key < table[mid].key)
            right = mid - 1;
        else
            left = mid + 1;
    }

    if (search == -1) {
        cout << "\nИскомого ключа не существует в таблице!";
        return;
    }

    if (search >= SIZE / 2)
        cout << "\nВ левой части относительно 50 чисел больше, чем в правой части!";
    else
        cout << "\nВ правой части относительно 50 чисел больше, чем в левой части!";
}
```